# MySQL query for page revisions

Tags: mysql

Ok, i have a table with the following columns

id | page_id | version | gold_master

so there will be multiple page_id's but only one of them will be gold_master. However some rows will have a higher version number than the gold_master but not be the gold master.

How can i select all rows that have a higher version than the gold_master but not BE the gold_master.

So far i have the "not be the gold_master" part from the other bit is perplexing me!

Comment: Post some code you already have.

Comment: well its a query but in cakephp so its just a conditions array...

Comment: post some sample data then :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this

```
SELECT * FROM your_table where version > (select version from your_table where gold_master=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd have two tables: one for `pages` and one for `page_revisions` that actually holds the content.

Your `pages` table would define a primary ID and also the current revision ID. The `page_revisions` table would hold the page title, content, and any other data you wanted to store for a page. This table would have a foreign key on `page_id`, as well as a `timestamp` so you can see when revisions were created and rank them as such. This table would also have its own primary key.

As the `page_revisions` table has its own primary ID, you can then use this in your `pages` table as `revision_id`. So the latest revision may not be the current revision, as you can set `revision_id` to an earlier revision.

Hopefully this makes sense. Let me know if it doesn't.

EDIT: Your actually query would look something like this:

```
SELECT p.id, r.title, r.content, r.created
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN page_revisions r
ON p.revision_id = r.id
WHERE p.id = 1
LIMIT 1
```